# Calculating the sign of a NxN determinant

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there a more efficient way to determine the sign (negative or positive or zero) of a determinant than calculating the full value of the determinant and comparing it with zero?

Comment: This sounds more like a math question than a programming question. It's certainly not specific to C#.

Comment: Good point. Since the goal is actual implementation details more than theory, what kind of answers would I receive?

Comment: are you looking for IComparable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are methods, that can *approximate* the determinat of an *integer matrix* faster, than computing the exact value. These methods are usually  used to compute the sign, since there is a great probability of a correct result. See [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.10.4850&bvm=bv.45368065,d.Yms&cad=rja) for much more details.

However AFAIK there is no *exact method* of computing sign of determinant faster than computing the value itself.